# Running two dynamic sql create scripts causes 'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first statement in a query batch.' error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012, ado.net

I have a c# method that runs sql command against a data base it looks like this

```
    public DataTable RunSqlDataTable(string sql, string returnTableName = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sql))
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    DataTable table = new DataTable();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnTableName))
                        table.TableName = returnTableName;
                    // Execute reader allows for the primary key to be retrieved
                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo))
                    {
                        table.Load(reader);
                    }
                    return table;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I first run the code with this code

```
string slq = @"CREATE TABLE TestTable(
 [Id]  int  NOT NULL ,
 [col1]  int  NOT NULL
);"

sqlHelper.RunSqlDataTable(sql);
```

Then I run

```
sql = @"CREATE TRIGGER [trg_TestTable]
ON [TestTable]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS
  BEGIN
 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted)
 BEGIN
     INSERT OtherTable(A, B, C)
         SELECT 'XXX', inserted.Id, getdate()
         FROM inserted
 END

 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
 BEGIN
         INSERT OtherTable(A,B,C)
         SELECT 'XXX', deleted.Id, getdate()
         FROM deleted
 END
 END;

sqlHelper.RunSqlDataTable(sql);
```

but this second line throws an exception

'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first statement in a query batch.

This is distilled down to the minimum that still exhibits the issue.
In the actual code I create indexes and foreign keys and constraints before I finally add the trigger in all cases it is just the trigger that throws an exception.
I can't use GO as that is not valid T-Sql. I am using .net 4.5

Why do I get the exception as the CREATE TRIGGER sql is the only query in  that command?

Regards,
Nick

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The statement must be the first in the batch. That means, you can't create one string with both `CREATE TRIGGER` statements and execute it as a single command ie batch. `GO` is an SSMS and sqlcmd command that separates batches. When you execute statements from a client, the batch is the entire string that you send when you execute a single command

Comment: Not sure where do you trigger that error. If your string is just a CREATE TRIGGER command then there is no other commands embedded in the string so this error should not happen. However calling that RunSqlDataTable seems to be pretty wrong here. You have no datatable to return and you don't need an SqlDataReader and a datatable Load call. You just need a connection, a command and a call to ExecuteNonQuery. Perhaps you could try to create another method to use for these kind of commands.

Comment: Steve - this method was trying to cover the both the case where a table might returned or not.  I was surprised that create table worked but create  trigger didn't.  Using ExecuteNonQuery fixed the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating trigger use [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.90).aspx) instead of your `RunSqlDataTable`.